# Can I set a pin high when it is connected to the SDA line?

Tags: stm32, i2c, wiring, protection, camera

I have an STM32 development board.
I want use DCMI (camera interface) with this board.

Unfortunately there is an AT24C02 E2PROM mounted on board with its SDA pin connected to the same pin used in the DCMI-connection (VSYNC.)

I checked datasheet but I am not very good at reading datasheet's analog sections.

I am writing this question as a double check to be sure there is no problem with connecting my camera like this.

I guess AT24C02's SDA does not short to GND and will not drain current (less than 5μA) when VSYNC line is high

[image]

Comment: No show stoppers, but that pull up resistor might hamper DMCI bandwidth. The EEPROM also loads the line a bit. I think I would remove the resistor and cut the EEPROM trace to have minimal stubs if you can figure it out.

Comment: @DKNguyen, VSYNC signal has a low frequency (i hope it is) VSYNC only toggle once a frame changes, so its about 20~40 times per second. i am just worry about over current

Answer (score 1):

As described in your question, you have a development board that connects a pin on its STM32 MCU to both the E2PROM SDA pin and the dedicated DCMI connector's VSYNC pin.

The board designer should have taken the loading effect of the E2PROM circuit into account when also connecting it up to the DCMI connector. They should also have performed at least some basic testing of this.

So you should have no problems. However, it is worth searching the support and discussion webpages on the board manufacturer's website for any problems users have had doing this.

Comment: unfortunately there is no DCMI connector but many male headers. the MCU provides 4 i2c, each provide more than 1 options for choosing SDA/SCL pins, but the worst one picked by designer

Answer (score 0):

In theory, it is always possible that for some reason the EEPROM might keep SDA low, but it will be very rare.

In practice, on powerup the EEPROM I2C interface should start from idle state and SDA will be in high-impedance state, held high by the resistor.

As the VSYNC signal used as SDA would pull low and push high, the EEPROM should not see any valid data transmissions if SCL does not toggle. If SCL is held high by the resistor, the falling and rising edges on SDA should look like start and stop conditions on the I2C bus, and since no addresses or data is ever transmitted to the EEPROM it should just ignore the VSYNC on data.

Comment: first thanks, the SCL is always in HIGH state, you said in theory SDA goes low, when it does, is there 0 resistance? i mean should SDA-low drain (or leak) to much current?

Comment: The SDA is an open-drain output. Datasheet specifies that at 3.0V supply and sinking 2.1mA the voltage will be at most 0.4V. That equates roughly with a 190 ohm resistor to ground, but at higher supply voltage the output impedance will usually be stronger.